# Defining normal-ordering in an OPE calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

Suppose $\phi_1, \phi_2, \psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ are free fields of a two-dimensional CFT with propagators on the plane given by

$$\phi_1(y)\phi_1(z) \sim -\log(y-z),\quad\phi_2(y)\phi_2(z) \sim -\log(y-z), \quad \psi(y)\bar{\psi}(z) \sim (y-z)^{-1}.$$

Utilizing the definition of normal-ordering given in Appendix B in Chapter 6 of [1], i. e.,
$$(AB)(z) = \oint dy \; A(y) B(z),$$
I want to calculate the single pole in the OPE between $(e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}\psi)(y)$ and $(e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}\bar{\psi})(z)$. For that, it is useful to know the following relations

$$e^{-\phi_1}(y)e^{\phi_1}(z) \sim (y-z)e^{-\phi_1}(y)e^{\phi_1}(z), \quad e^{-i\phi_2}(y)e^{2i\phi_2}(z)  \sim (y-z)^{-2}e^{-i\phi_2}(y)e^{2i\phi_2}(z). $$

I start using the definition, eqn. (6.206) of [1]. For the single pole in the OPE between $(e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}\psi)(y)$ and $(e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}\bar{\psi})(z)$ we then have

$$\oint dy \; (e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}\psi)(y)(e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}\bar{\psi})(z)= \\
= \oint dy \oint \frac{dx}{x-z}\bigg[(y-x)^{-1}(e^{i\phi_2}\psi)(x)\bar{\psi}(z) -e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}(x)e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}(z)(y-z)^{-1} \bigg], $$
where a contraction between $(e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}\psi)(y)$ and $e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}(x)$ was done to get the first term, and a contraction between $(e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}\psi)(y)$ and $\bar{\psi}(z)$ was done to get the second one.

Now, to proceed, one needs to do the full OPEs between $(e^{i\phi_2}\psi)(x)$ and $\bar{\psi}(z)$, in the first term, and between $e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}(x)$ and $e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}(z)$ in the second term above. Only the first regular terms of both OPEs will contribute to the single pole, writing only these we have

$$\oint dy \oint \frac{dx}{x-z}\bigg[(y-x)^{-1} \bigg(\partial e^{i\phi_2}(z) +(e^{i\phi_2}\psi\bar{\psi})(z) \bigg) - (y-z)^{-1} \bigg(\partial e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}(z)e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}(z) \bigg) \bigg], $$
where $\partial e^{i \phi_2}$ comes from expanding $e^{i \phi_2}(x)$ to remove the pole coming from contracting $\psi(x)$ and $\bar{\psi}(z)$ and $\partial e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}$ comes from expanding $e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}(x)$ to remove the pole from the OPE of $e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}(x)$ and $e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}(z)$. After doing the integrals one is left with

$$\partial e^{i\phi_2}(z) +(e^{i\phi_2}\psi\bar{\psi})(z) - \partial e^{\phi_1 + 2i\phi_2}(z)e^{-\phi_1 -i \phi_2}(z).$$

Now is the point where comes my question: How does one define the above expression?

Note that I have written explicitly the normal-order in $(e^{i\phi_2}\psi\bar{\psi})(z)$, but I don't know what to do with the remaining terms or, I should say, how to normal order them. For example, should I write $\partial e^{i\phi_2}(z)$ as $(\partial(i \phi_2)e^{i\phi_2})(z)$ or as $(e^{i\phi_2}\partial(i \phi_2))(z)$? And similar for the other term, should I write it as $(e^{i \phi_2} \partial(\phi_1 + 2i \phi_2))(z)$ or as  $(\partial(\phi_1 + 2i \phi_2)e^{i \phi_2})(z)$? These are examples of questions that made me stuck in the last expression, without knowing if it makes sense of not.

---

[1] P. Di Francesco, P. Mathieu and D. Senechal, *Conformal field theory*, Graduate Texts in
Contemporary Physics. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1997.

Comment: Which page is the $(\phi_1, \phi_2, \psi)$ system taken from? Is it from another reference?

Comment: @Qmechanic This system is not in the book, these are some free fields defined by their propagators. $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are also known as chiral bosons because of their OPEs.

Comment: Don't you just need to set your convention for normal ordering of for the product of a single filed, e.g. from right to left or from left to right, i.e. $(\phi\phi\phi)= (\phi(\phi\phi))$ or $(\phi\phi\phi)=((\phi\phi)\phi)$?

Comment: @Oбжорoв I don't know, that's what I am asking

Comment: @Slayer147 It's been many years ago for me, but that is what I remember. And I believe one usually chooses right to left, i.e the first formula.